# How to sum all values based on two columns

Tags: mysql

I have such data:

```
    user|time|date
    1   |10  |2020-01-01
    1   |15  |2020-01-01
    2   |30  |2020-01-01
    1   |20  |2020-01-02
    1   |20  |2020-01-02
```

I want to add the sum(TIME column) of all data meeting the criteria to each row(sum of rows having the same USER and DATE e.g user=1, date=2020-01-01).
I want to use the sum later to calculate the percentage

```
user|time|date      |sum
1   |10  |2020-01-01|25
1   |15  |2020-01-01|25
2   |30  |2020-01-01|30
1   |20  |2020-01-02|40
1   |20  |2020-01-02|40
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the sum on each row, you have to calculate it in a separate query and join it to the table.

```
SELECT t.user, t.`time`, t.`date`, st.mySum
FROM your_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT user, `date`, SUM(`time`) AS mySum
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY user, `date` 
) st ON t.user = st.user AND t.`date` = st.`date`
```

And when you don't use key words as column names, you don't have to quote them each time with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

For MySql 8.0+ this can be done with `SUM()` window function:

```
select *, sum(time) over (partition by user, date) `sum`
from tablename
order by date, user
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qkY8JdoRC9pwTWSZKxEvat/0).
Results:

```
| user | time | date               | sum |
| ---- | ---- | ------------------ | --- |
| 1    | 10   | 2020-01-01         | 25  |
| 1    | 15   | 2020-01-01         | 25  |
| 2    | 30   | 2020-01-01         | 30  |
| 1    | 20   | 2020-01-02         | 40  |
| 1    | 20   | 2020-01-02         | 40  |
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.